# Union many tables SQLalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, orm, union

I have a list of table names with many tables (a few dozen) in a Postgres DB mapped to SQLalchemy ORM objects. All of them have common columns and I would like to union a sub-set of columns from all of the tables into one CTE or subquery to use in further queries etc.

I know that using `table1.union(table2)` will union 2 tables. However, I do not want to copy paste dozens of time the same code.

Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Thank you.

**Solution:**

Actually it is simple as pointed out by [Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2036070/ian-wilson).

```
all_tables = []
for table in list_of_tables:
    this_table = select(.....)
    all_tables.append(this_table)

# union
unioned_tables = union(*all_tables)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can keep chaining that union like

```py
a = table1.union(table2)
a = a.union(table3)
```

But also there are functions that take a dynamic number of tables to union as positional args:

[union](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.union) or [union_all](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.union_all)

```py
q = union(table1, table2, table3)
```